# Nested for-loop scope

Tags: java

I've been trying to tackle a programming-problem,and have come across a scoping problem. Here is a SCE of the problem:

```
for (int Hole1 = 1; Hole1 < beavers; Hole1++) {
        list = exampleList;

        for (int t = 0; t < Hole1; t++) {
            temp.add(list.get(0));
            list.remove(0);
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < Hole1; p++) {
            list.add(temp.get(temp.size() - 1));
            temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
        }
        exampleList2 = list;

        for (int Hole2 = 1; Hole2 < beavers; Hole2++) {
            list = exampleList2;

            for (int t = 0; t < Hole2; t++) {
                temp.add(list.get(0));
                list.remove(0);
            }

            for (int p = 0; p < Hole2; p++) {
                list.add(temp.get(temp.size() - 1));
                temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
            }
            exampleList3 = list;

            for (int Hole3 = 1; Hole3 < beavers; Hole3++) {
                list = exampleList3;

                for (int t = 0; t < Hole3; t++) {
                    temp.add(list.get(0));
                    list.remove(0);
                }

                for (int p = 0; p < Hole3; p++) {
                    list.add(temp.get(temp.size() - 1));
                    temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
                }

                System.out.println(list.toString() + " " + Hole1 + " " + Hole2 + " " + Hole3);
                if (check(list))
                    System.out.println("match");
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that *examplelist3* changes value for every iteration of the *hole3* `for loop`, but from my understanding each `loop` completes it's iterations before moving on. Anyone have an idea of what's going on?

EDIT* removed the SCE and posted the code instead

Comment: Maybe you can add what you are trying to achieve? It seems like you are doing some nested iterations/assignments in some awkward way.

Comment: `each for-loop completes it's iterations before moving on.` That is what happens actually.

Comment: Well, it's a a problem from a competition I couldn't crack. You start with a list of 5 4 3 2 1, running them through 3 "holes" which are between 1 and n-1 deep. [the problem can be seen here on page 5](http://www.progolymp.se/static/arkiv/kval15.pdf). Then to match them in a certain ortder and get the hole depths.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the code in the question, all the variables - `list`, `startlist`, `examplelist2` and `examplelist3` - refer to the same list object. This means that if you make any changes to any of these variables, all other variables will show the updated list since they all reference the same object.

Thus even though the code updates `list` in the 3rd `for` loop, the changes will also be reflected in `exampleList3` since both variables point to the same object in the heap.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/209008) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

> from my understanding each for-loop completes it's iterations before moving on.

Thats true.

What is happening in your code? Iteration of `for(hole2)` is being done complete, which means that in each iteration will execute `for(hole3)`, because is inside the scope of `for(hole2)`

Each iteration of `for(hole2)` will always be this code:

```
list = examplelist2;
//sorting list
examplelist3 = list;

for(hole3){
    list = examplelist3;
    //sorting list
    //check if matching 
}
```

What implies to iterate over `for(hole3)` each time.